# How to run different python scripts from command line by passing the script name as argument

Tags: shell-script, python

I am using CentOs 6.
I have got two scripts test1.py and test2.py in same directory.

I am running one test at a time as below from terminal:

py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html test1.py

I want to create a shell script so that I can pass the script name (test1.py, test2.py) as parameter .

Comment: #!/bin/bash                                                                                                        py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html $testname

Comment: The paramters you pass to the script can be access as `$1`, `$2`, etc. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script `run_test.sh` as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Take the first argument with $1
py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html $1
```

To run this script execute

```
$ bash run_test.sh <name_of_python_file>
```

Or make it executable with

```
$ chmod +x run_test.sh
```

and then you can launch it with

```
./run_test.sh <name_of_python_file>
```